# Firebase how can I add a child node with a given name?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have a `/users` folder on Firebase realtime db, with inside various `UID`,
how can I add a child called `/history` under an UID ?

Using `.child('users').child(UID).push()` it creates a unique id, I'd like it to be called "history" instead, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `push()` generates a new unique location under the reference on which you call it. To instead control the key of the location you write to. use `child`:

```
ref.child('users').child(UID).child("history").set("hello")
```

---

If you'd instead want to create a new unique child node *under* the `history` node, you'd do:

```
ref.child('users').child(UID).child("history").push("hello")
```

Comment: thanks it worked, now my code ref.child(userId).orderByChild('n').equalTo(name).once("value", function(snapshot) { doesn't work anymore thought, I think it's due to the "history" child among all the unique id children.. these children nodes have pairs "n" and "c" (content) inside, instead "history" only has "h" inside. I can't understand why if i delete the "history" node all works again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there. It's probably best to post a new question, with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces this problem.